# I have a index.php file in a Directory i want that to be the default directory

Tags: .htaccess

- Includes // contains all the conection files etc
- public  // contains index.php file and css, js n stuff

usually when someone types my domain name for eg: www.abc.com it will show directory listing. i dont want that to happen i want htaccess to go looking for index.php in public folder something like this www.abc.com/public/index.php or may be hide the directory public and it should display like this www.abc.com/index.php

Comment: Sounds like you need to change your [`DocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot). That being said, this might be more a question for ServerFault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+public/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^$ /public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: What URL did you try? Make sure you have enabled mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf.

Comment: but how can i hide the directory ???? like for example the actul url is http:abc.com/public/index.php but i wanna show it as http://abc.com instead of the full url

Comment: You'll need an additional rule for that, let me add it here.

Comment: ur so helpful ^_^ :D thanx

Comment: nope its not working its going to the default direcotry the wamp server page

Comment: What URL did you see in the browser finally? In your default wamp directory there might be an `index.html` or `index.php`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31034/discussion-between-unique-devil-and-anubhava)